# How to refresh my component when deleting a custom object record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-object, related-list, actionlink

I have a custom object displayed as a related list in the related page of it's lookup object. When user delete the record using the delete link button, I want another component refreshed. 
[image]

I tried to use aura:dependency and force:refreshview. It only works when you edit or create a record. When deleting the record, it's not refreshing the component

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:editRecord" type="EVENT" />
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without the code it's hard to say, but maybe a good option it's to use an event.
Every time you delete a record the event is fired and tells the other component that changes were made.